# AppStore domain for Firebase OAuth?

Tags: firebase, app-store, firebase-authentication, testflight

i'm making an app with Ionic and using Firebase for user authentication.

I'm trying to make a Facebook login using the Firebase API:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(provider);
```

It works perfectly in the localhost. But when i build the app and send it to the AppStore (TestFlight), it gives me this error:

```
This domain is not authorized to run this operation. Add it to the OAuth redirect domains list in the Firebase console -> Auth section -> Sign in method tab.
```

What domain should I enter in the authorized domains list for the OAuth work in the AppStore/TestFlight?

Comment: somebody, heeeelp!

Comment: Is this a mobile Ionic app? or a web app? I am not sure about the environment this is hosted in. It may be hosted in a domain that is not whitelisted.